# Teamcity pass parameters between different builds (different build configrations)

Tags: build, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm using TeamCity Professional 2020.1.2 .
under a project I have multiple build configurations.
what I want to do is generate a random string in every build of build config "A"
and override it every time, build config "A" runs.
Then I need to use it somewhere in build config "B"

I know how to pass variables between build steps, but I don't know how to do the same between different build configurations.

```
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='env.path' value='/sample/path']"
```

I thought meybe there should be a global parameter registry which every build can read and write from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to use a snapshot dependency between build configurations?
In this case, you can access a parameter from another configuration in the chain by %dep.BUILD_ID.param%.
Here are two related pages in the documentation: ["Build dependencies"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/build-dependencies-setup.html#Parameters+in+dependent+builds) and ["Dependencies properties"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/predefined-build-parameters.html#Dependencies+Properties).

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without adding Dependencies? for e.g sending a Rest api